# Where can I find audio configuration on Debian Linux

Tags: audio, debian

I have a new laptop. Because I switched from a desktop computer my usage is a little different. Also, because this laptop is much more powerful than my old computer I switched from Xfce4 to Cinnamon. I don't know if that latter fact is relevant.

So I installed Debian Jessie, with the Cinnamon desktop, and my home partition was completely empty so that the configuration is now mostly the defaults. There is something with my system which I am finding extremely irritating. That is, my sound settings keep changing.

Say I bring my laptop into my office, plug my screen, keyboard and speakers in, because I want to go to put some music on. Fine, I'll fire up rhythmbox and find the playlist I want, and press play. Then I find that the sound has been muted. I did not mute it myself, but I think something muted it when I plugged the speakers in.

Then I'll load a page in firefox. That page has an advertisement or a video that emits sound, so that suddenly mutes the headphone jack and puts the internal speakers on. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

It's a fact that `pulseaudio` is not so stable nowadays in all situations. Use `pavucontrol` and `pasystray` for controlling volume settings continuously, or you can remove pulseaudio completely and using pure `alsa`, but it may do other annoying things. 
Try to add `jessie-backports` repository and upgrade pulseaudio to 7.0.

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```